# Boost function: boost::filesystem::file_size errors

Tags: windows, boost, boost-filesystem

I tryed to use the file_size function on "hiberfil.sys" file, but got the system:32 error code.
I tryed to read the documentation of the function, and there was written that if its a regular file (and it is as i checked) it has to work.
this is the code:

```
boost::filesystem::path p="c:\\hiberfil.sys";
std::cout<<boost::filesystem::file_size(p);
```

any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

The file is a memory snapshot for Windows' hibernation, it is locked and you won't be able to get its file size with boost or otherwise.

You can natively read the directory entry on Windows to obtain the file size ([see an MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but the value would be an approximation at best, since the file is locked.